# mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have installed XAMPP on my Ubuntu 14.0.04 and I'm trying to connect to my MySQL server from PHP file but I'm getting an error:

> **Warning**:  mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/value.php** on
>    line **3**
>   not connected

my `value.php` file contains

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost:3307', 'root', '');
if ($con) echo 'Connected';
else echo 'not connected';
---
?>
```

and my MySQL server is up and running and my server is also running.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysql_*`, as those functions are deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Firstly, Don't use mysql as it is depreciated, 1. Does your server has `mysql.sock` ? 2. Do you close the connection in your previous operation ?

Comment: Is the link to localhost on port 3307 is set somewhere ?

Answer (score 7):

Which version of mysql are you using?

Try this

```
 127.0.0.1:your-port-number
```

like

```
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3307', 'root', ''); // or 3306 whatever your port number is
```

instead of `localhost`

I too had this problem, but this link helped me [Warning: mysql_connect()](https://webdevjourney.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/warning-mysql_connect-function-mysql-connect-no-such-file-or-directory/)

Comment: I LOVE YOU!!!!! took me unlit the break of dawn when the church bells rang to find this... in a literal sense XD and this is practically the only thing that actually worked!!!! thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mysql has got the location of the socket file wrong; and it can be fixed by simply setting the symbolic link to correct it.

The socket file (zero length file) will be either be available in /tmp/mysql.sock or /var/mysql/mysql.sock. Depending on which one is missing create a symbolic link for other.

```
cd /var 
sudo mkdir mysql
sudo chmod 755 mysql
cd mysql
ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```